# Add another column to a dataframe containing the name of the non-zero features

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe. For example, some rows of it is as follows:

```
 Id     Context    Power    Security     Humality   Tolerance  

 0       have.       0         0           1           0
 1       has         1         1           1           1
 2       has         0         0           1           1
```

I want to add another column with the title 'values' containing features that are not zero. So that the above dataset can be as follows:

```
Id     Context         Values 

 0       have        ['Humality']
 1       has         ['Power', 'Security', 'Humality', 'Tolerence']
 2       has         ['Humality', 'Tolerence']
```

This dataset has 5000 rows minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner solution:

```
df["Values"] = df.drop("Context", axis=1).apply(lambda row: row[row != 0].index.tolist(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
v = df.iloc[:,2:]

v.dot(v.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')
```

or

```
v.mul(v.columns).where(v.eq(1)).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
0                                [Humality]
1    [Power, Security, Humality, Tolerance]
2                     [Humality, Tolerance]
```